# How to use js in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I just want an alert to work and then I will go on my own, but when I write `alert()` in my `recources/js/app.js` it doesn't work, but my scss works, I ran `npm run watch` doesn't help, what to do, and why I can't find any information on google on just how to use js on laravel? :/

my mix file
[image: mix]

my js file
[image: js]

Comment: Are you including the JS file from the public folder in your blade file?

Comment: hmm, no isn't it being automatically? because my scss is compiling and sending to public/css/app.css automatically, I am very new to Laravel
Yes that was the case, please answer it I will accept it :)

Comment: Mix is just compiling the files, they aren't automatically injected into your blade files. Just take a look at your blade file, you should see something like `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` and `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Oh, I forgot that I've deleted the dafault `welcome.blade.php` and created a new blank one lol, thanks for the answer, just post it I will accept and upvote it :D

Comment: I don't think the welcome blade includes them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix is just compiling the files, they aren't automatically injected into your blade files. Just take a look at your blade file, you should see something like

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add this code in your app.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```